# Vertex displacement breaking mesh

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I'm doing some OpenGL stuff in Java (lwjgl) for a project, part of which includes importing 3d models in OBJ format. Everything *looks* ok, until I try to displace vertices, then the models break up, you can see right through them.
Here is Suzanne from blender, UV mapped with a completely black texture (for visibility's sake). In the frag shader I'm adding some white colour to the fragment depending on the fragments angle between its normal and the world's up vector:

[image]

So far so good. But when I apply a small Y component displacement to the same vertices, I expect to see the faces 'stretch' up. Instead this happens:

[image]

Vertex shader:

```
#version 150

in vec3 position;
in vec2 texCoords;
in vec3 normal;

void main()
{
    vertPosModel = position;                        

    cosTheta = dot(vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), normal);    

    if(cosTheta > 0.0 && cosTheta < 1.0)     
        vertPosModel += vec3(0.0, 0.15, 0.0); 

    gl_Position = transform * vec4(vertPosModel, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 150

uniform sampler2D objTexture;
in vec2 texcoordOut;
in float cosTheta;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = vec4(texture(objTexture, texcoordOut.st).rgb, 1.0) + vec4(cosTheta);

}
```

Comment: Please, before you just vote down, tell me how I can improve my question. Don't be a coward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, your algorithm offsets a vertex's position, based on a property derived from the vertex's normal. This will only produce a connected mesh if your mesh is completely smooth. That is, where two triangles meet, the normals of the shared vertices must be the same on both sides of the triangle.

If the model has discontinuous normals over the surface, then breaks can appear anywhere that the normal stops being continuous. That is, the edges where there is a normal discontinuity may become disconnected.

I'm pretty sure that Blender3D can generate a smooth version of Suzanne. So... did you generate a smooth mesh? Or is it faceted?

Comment: Yes if you mean the left toolbar in Blender where you can select "Smooth or Flat" shading. I've tried both, but if it only changes the normals I don't see how it could fix the issue because currently I'm not using normals for any lighting calculations (that's in my todo list).

Comment: @peanutops: As I said, you're using normals for your *position* calculations. If the normals aren't well connected, then the *positions* computed from them won't be connected either.

Comment: I guess I need to rewrite my .obj importer so that shared vertices have their face normals merged into shared vertex normals. I did something similar yesterday - exporting from blender an .x3d instead (the normals list is exported 'per vertex' not per face), though after reading that into a vbo half of my faces were missing, sigh.

Comment: OK problem solved. I re-exported all my models in x3d, stl, and ply formats, and I even wrote basic importers for each so I could see what was happening with the data. Nothing worked until I scrapped my models and made new ones with smooth shading selected in Blender from the beginning. My original OBJ importer code was working just fine, and it was the shading model affecting the normals, as you suggested. Damn the abnormal normals :-) Thanks a lot.